# Jquery show hide text on image click

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have multiple images and i want to show information about the image only when user click it and hide it when user tap the close button.
please help me .
here is my code 
HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-6 ">
                    <div class="img__wrap" >
                        <img src="./images/RaviDhariwal.jpg" alt="team" class="img-responsive img__img" >
                        <div class="img_person">
                            <p class="name-pos">RAVI DHARIWAL</p>
                            <p class="designation">CHAIRMAN</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="img__description" data-popup="popup-1">
                            <div class="float-right popup-closeimg close-hover" data-toggle="popover">X</div>
                            <div class="img-desc-title">RAVI DHARIWAL</div>

                            <div class="designation">CHAIRMAN</div>
                            <div class="person_detail">
                                An IIT/K, IIMC alumnus, Ravi started his career with Unilever in India, and, went on to head Soaps marketing when he joined PepsiCo as its first employee in India. 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JQuery

```
   $('.img__wrap').on('click', function(e)  {
    $(this).find('.img__description').css("opacity",1);
    // e.preventDefault();
});

$('.close-hover').on('click', function(e)  {
    $(this).parent('.img__wrap').css("opacity",0);

    // e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: any errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the demo: https://codepen.io/rearmustak/pen/BZpEaX
You can get a solution here

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-6 ">
  <div class="img__wrap" >
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="team" class="img-responsive img__img" >
    <div class="img_person">
      <p class="name-pos">RAVI DHARIWAL</p>
      <p class="designation">CHAIRMAN</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img__description" data-popup="popup-1">
      <div class="float-right popup-closeimg close-hover" data-toggle="popover">X</div>
      <div class="img-desc-title">RAVI DHARIWAL</div>

      <div class="designation">CHAIRMAN</div>
      <div class="person_detail">
        An IIT/K, IIMC alumnus, Ravi started his career with Unilever in India, and, went on to head Soaps marketing when he joined PepsiCo as its first employee in India. 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Use this css code

```
.img__description{
  display: none;
}
.close-hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is the jquery code:

```
$('.img__wrap img').on('click', function(e)  {
    $('.img__description').fadeIn();
    // e.preventDefault();
});

$('.close-hover').on('click', function(e)  {
    $(this).parent('.img__description').fadeOut();

    // e.preventDefault();
});
```

call jquery library also

Answer (score 0):

How about using toggle (to show/hide), not opacity?

```
$('.img__wrap').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.img__description').toggle();
});
```

This way, they can re-click the image to hide the desc, or, use the close button. If you ONLY want them to open the desc upon clicking, then use .show() instead of .toggle().

And the close button should be (I don't think you mean to refer to .img_wrap in your existing code - just get the .parent() - easy):

```
$('.close-hover').on('click', function(e)  {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be:

```
$('.close-hover').on('click', function(e)  {
    $(this).parent().css("opacity",0);

    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I see some inconsistencies here. You are changing the opacity for `.img__description` and then, `.img__wrap`

Answer (score 0):

Try Using  `$(this).closest('.img__wrap').css("opacity", 0);`

```js
$('.img__wrap').on('click', function(e) { 
  $(this).find('.img__description').css("opacity", 1);
  // e.preventDefault();
});

$('.close-hover').on('click', function(e) { 
  $(this).closest('.img__wrap').css("opacity", 0);

  // e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.img__description{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-6 ">
  <div class="img__wrap">
    <img src="./images/RaviDhariwal.jpg" alt="team" class="img-responsive img__img">
    <div class="img_person">
      <p class="name-pos">RAVI DHARIWAL</p>
      <p class="designation">CHAIRMAN</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img__description" data-popup="popup-1">
      <div class="float-right popup-closeimg close-hover" data-toggle="popover">X</div>
      <div class="img-desc-title">RAVI DHARIWAL</div>

      <div class="designation">CHAIRMAN</div>
      <div class="person_detail">
        An IIT/K, IIMC alumnus, Ravi started his career with Unilever in India, and, went on to head Soaps marketing when he joined PepsiCo as its first employee in India.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If you want hide and show you could simply toggle a class  `$(this).find('.img__description').toggleClass("hidden");`

```js
 $('.img__wrap').on('click', function(e)  {
    $(this).find('.img__description').toggleClass("hidden");
    // e.preventDefault();
});

$('.close-hover').on('click', function(e)  {
    $(this).closest('.img__wrap').css("opacity",0);

    // e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-6 ">
  <div class="img__wrap">
    <img src="./images/RaviDhariwal.jpg" alt="team" class="img-responsive img__img">
    <div class="img_person">
      <p class="name-pos">RAVI DHARIWAL</p>
      <p class="designation">CHAIRMAN</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img__description" data-popup="popup-1">
      <div class="float-right popup-closeimg close-hover" data-toggle="popover">X</div>
      <div class="img-desc-title">RAVI DHARIWAL</div>

      <div class="designation">CHAIRMAN</div>
      <div class="person_detail">
        An IIT/K, IIMC alumnus, Ravi started his career with Unilever in India, and, went on to head Soaps marketing when he joined PepsiCo as its first employee in India.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is updated code

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-6 ">
                    <div class="img__wrap" >
                        <img id="img_1" src="./images/RaviDhariwal.jpg" alt="team" class="img-responsive img__img" >
                        <div class="img_person">
                            <p class="name-pos">RAVI DHARIWAL</p>
                            <p class="designation">CHAIRMAN</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="des_img_1" class="img__description" data-popup="popup-1">
                            <div class="float-right popup-closeimg close-hover" data-toggle="popover">X</div>
                            <div class="img-desc-title">RAVI DHARIWAL</div>

                            <div class="designation">CHAIRMAN</div>
                            <div class="person_detail">
                                An IIT/K, IIMC alumnus, Ravi started his career with Unilever in India, and, went on to head Soaps marketing when he joined PepsiCo as its first employee in India. 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JQuery

```
   $('.img_1').on('click', function(e)  {
    $('.des_img_1').show();
    // e.preventDefault();
});

$('.close-hover').on('click', function(e)  {
    $('.des_img_1').hide();    
    // e.preventDefault();
});
```